# What certifications are needed for GPS/GSM devices in AirPort?

Tags: gps, gsm, production, certification

I am kind new in industrial engineering my company has order for several devices which would be used in airport Technics cars. Do I need some kind of special certification for devices that I create to be allowed used in airports?

Comment: First start by telling us where you are (there's a reason why there's such a field in the profile) and what kind of devices are the devices you're making.

Comment: Now in Lithuania, future all europe and maybe USA. It would be device which interface to airport car computers (gas fillers, small cars and etc.) collect data gets gps data and send it via GSM to main server

Comment: What are "airport Technics cars"?

Comment: [link](http://www.modelcorner.co.uk/prodimages/GJARPTSETA%20web%20image.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Factors to consider prior to certification**

You will need to first clarify to yourself, and second formally document, each of the following:

- the constituent parts in your device (as well as whether the internal parts you might be using themselves have been pre-certified)
- whether your devices will be used within just the airport vs. on-board aircraft
- any GSM provider(s) you may intend to work with
- the target countries/region(s) of operation of the device

**2. Regulatory agencies/standards**

The following details are provided with a little more weight on United States regulations, but also with some focus on general European regulations. With that said, note that there are a variety of specific regulatory standards to which you need to ensure your device, and its components, conform. In terms of certifications, you'll need to research and get certified by some or all of the following (again, it would depend on the above list of factors for your specific case):

- Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) regulations
- Federal Communications Commission (FCC) certification
- PTCRB (originally: PCS Type Certification Review Board) certification
- Carrier certification-testing

**3. Obtaining the specifics on applying for the certifications**

There is a wealth of information available out there regarding the specifcs of the above, obtainable via the internet or in paper form from the governing bodies of each of the above. Before you head to the websites/phone numbers of the regulatory agencies, I recommend you read the relevant sections of these four documents to get a good start on what is involved:

- [Certification Overview for the Americas Region](http://www.roundsolutions.com/techdocs/docs_gsm_modules/Whitepaper-Certifications_Overview_for_the_Americas_Region_r0.pdf)
- [FCC certification for host devices with integrated wireless modules](http://www.rfi-global.com/images/uploads/file/FCC%20Certification%20-%20Overview%20For%20Integrated%20Wireless%20Devices.pdf)
- [PTCRB certification for host devices with integrated cellular modules](http://www.rfi-global.com/images/uploads/file/PTCRCB%20Certification%20-%20Overview%20For%20Integrated%20Wireless%20Devices.pdf)
- [European certification for host devices with integrated wireless modules](http://www.rfi-global.com/images/uploads/file/European%20Certification%20-%20Overview%20For%20Integrated%20Wireless%20Devices.pdf)

Since the above documents are provided for varying regions, and since the documents are fairly extensive, you can start by funneling down the select requirements for just the first region in which you wish to launch your device.

Comment: Hmm, will be used only in airport trucks/cars not planes. Maybe do you know something more specific for europe?

Comment: The last link in my Answer is for Europe